# Add the same UIBarButtonItem to several UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I want to add the same `UIBarButtonItem` to several `UIViewController`s. I've done this previously by creating a parent `UIViewController` that manages to add the `UIBarButtonItem`s in `viewDidLoad`. But now I have many view controllers that inherit from different view controllers, so if I follow the same strategy I should create a `UIViewController` subclass for each one of the different view controllers.

What I am actually doing is to configure the navigation bar buttons in my `BaseViewController`, the parent controller of all of the rest, depending on the flags I set when creating the child view controllers. With this solution the code only relies on one view controller, but I would like if there are more elegant options to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of solutions is to use objective-c [**category**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html). In this case, you will create common method for all UIViewControllers, that will create and configure UIBarButton

Comment: Do you mean an ``UIViewController`` category?

Comment: @amb sure, it should be `UIViewController's` category. also, it can be category for any other class that is base for your group of view controllers, but if you have class like that, I think it will be more properly to implement separated method in that base class.

Comment: I've just implemented this as a category of my ``BaseViewController``. Works perfectly and is the best solution I've seen so far. I cannot implement this as a method in my base VC because it needs to instantiate another VC that inherits from the base one.